# How does Color.Lerp works?

Tags: unityscript, lerp

I want to understand how does `Color.Lerp` works in unity.
According to [this page](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html) it is quite clear to understand how to use it but I'm interested in how it is implemented. Does it work on RGB channels? and how? In the docs it says that the `t` factor is clamped between 0 and 1 so i wonder to know on which values Lerp works with `Color`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Color.Lerp in Unity works just as any [lerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) implementation, which works like this:

```
float lerp(float a, float b, float t)
{
    t = clamp01(t);
    return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

Or with multiple components, like Color:

```
Color lerp(Color a, Color b, float t)
{
    t = clamp01(t);
    return new Color(
        a.r + (b.r - a.r) * t,
        a.g + (b.g - a.g) * t,
        a.b + (b.b - a.b) * t,
        a.a + (b.a - a.a) * t
    );
}
```

Comment: **tl;dr:** it lerps each RGBA channel separately.